# I get the following error when i try to execute my code. ORA-00905: missing keyword 00905. 00000 - "missing keyword" : Error at Line: 11 Column: 28

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting the following error when i try execute the code, please help :)

Thank you

```
SELECT 
    STUDENTID, FIRSTNAME, SURNAME, HOMEWORKID
FROM 
    TBLSTUDENT
JOIN 
    TBLHOMEWORK.HOMEWORKID, TBLHOMEWORK.STUDENTID, TBLHOMEWORK.EVENTTYPE
WHERE 
    TBLHOMEWORK.EVENTTYPE = 'Meeting'
JOIN 
    TBLMEETING.HOMEWORKID, TBLMEETING.LOCATION
ORDER BY 
    HOMEWORKID;
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, the layout of the tables, and a description of what you want to do would all help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Keyword in JOIN syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470802/missing-keyword-in-join-syntax)

Answer (score 3):

Your query just makes no sense.  A SQL query starts with `SELECT`.  It then has one `FROM` clause that contains all references to tables.  `JOIN` is an operator between two tables that requires an `ON` clause.  There is only one `WHERE`, with all conditions for filtering.

I am imagining this is what you intend:

```
SELECT s.STUDENTID, s.FIRSTNAME, s.SURNAME, h.HOMEWORKID,
       m.LOCATION
FROM TBLSTUDENT s JOIN
     TBLHOMEWORK h
     ON s.STUDENTID = h.STUDENTID JOIN
     TBLMEETING m
     ON m.HOMEWORKID = h.HOMEWORKID 
WHERE h.EVENTTYPE = 'Meeting'
ORDER BY h.HOMEWORKID;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I really appreciate it.